# ios after camera closed, how to make status bar show

Tags: ios, camera, statusbar

when the camera picker is dismessed, the status bar is still hidden.
I try to use prefersStatusBarHidden to show status bar, but it does not work.

```
var statusBarHidden = false {
    didSet {
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?){
picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        self.statusBarHidden = false
    }        
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController){
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
        self.statusBarHidden = false
    }
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

this is my code. what is wrong?

Comment: the action sheet cause the problem. i use action sheet to choose imagepicker sourceType. if i do not use action sheet everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether u put these codes here, maybe for some specific reasons I don't know?

`override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}`

I think this makes the status bar disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` in project `Info.plist` file, this allow you control hide or show status bar.

Comment: I set View controller-based status bar appearance = YES to Info.plist, but when the actionsheet show and present imagepickercontroller, after imagepicker dismiss, the statusbar is still hidden

Comment: Can you show the code how you present imagepickercontroller, maybe the actionSheet prevent something.